# Designing a $\beta(\delta) = \tilde{O}(H\sqrt{d})$ function that dominates another function which has $\log \beta(\delta)$ within it

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, inequality, asymptotics

I am trying to define a function $\beta(\delta)$ which will be a polynomial of $k,H,d$ and $1/\delta$ satisfying $\beta(\delta) = \tilde{O}(H\sqrt{d})$ where $\tilde{O}$ is similar to Big-O notation that ignores logarithmic terms. The only other requirement is that  $\beta(\delta)$ needs to dominate the following term.

$\text{RHS} = 2H\sqrt{d}\Bigl[\frac{1}{2}\log(k+1) + \log3\big\{2\sqrt{k^3} + (\frac{k}{H}\sqrt{\beta(\delta)} + \frac{k}{H}\sqrt{d} + k\sqrt{d})c\sqrt{\log(d/\delta)}\big\} + \log(1/\delta)\Bigr]^{1/2}$

that is we want
$\beta(\delta) \geq \text{RHS}$.

Note that $\text{RHS}$ has $\beta(\delta)$ within it. I am not sure how to approach this and would really appreciate any help.

I am essentially trying to do something like the following from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.00567.pdf

[image]
[image]

Comment: this hurts my eyes

Comment: same here man :(. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ok so here is a strategy that might work: let $\beta = x$ and then basically you want to solve $x \ge A(B+C \sqrt{x})^{1/2}$ where $A$ and $B$ are some terms that are fixed. Squaring and further simplifying, you want to solve $x^2 \ge a+b\sqrt{x}$ where $a,b$ are some other fixed terms which you can find. Now $x^2$ is just a quadratic and the other side is just a shifted sqrt(x) function.If you can figure out what a and b are (in particular which one is bigger, say b), you can further say its sufficient that $x^2 \ge b(1+\sqrt{x})$ which should be easier